# Page suddenly won't pull neither css or bootstrap

Tags: html, css, path

So I am working on a page, I did part of it yesterday and it worked fine, I continued doing the rest today, everything was fine. When I tried opening it as normal html page, CSS or BOOTSTRAP won't work only text of the page is displayed, But when I open VS CODE and run the site through "Live Server" extension it works perfectly fine???

I have not altered the paths to anything, and here is my link in head:

```
<link href="/appdata/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/appdata/radnik.css" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
```

Path of the page that I'm working on is:

```
C:\Users\MyPC\FixITSite\gradjevina\moler\marko-nikolic.html
```

I have tried changing paths, putting One dot "." in front of the "/" like so:

```
<link href="./appdata/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./appdata/radnik.css" />
```

Also tried putting two dots, still no success, one dot opens the "moler" folder, and two dots open "gradjevina" folder

Comment: if loading the page from filesystem instead of http won't give you further annoyances, and the problem is limited to the correct fetch of assets, instead of doing random attempts I suggest you to keep an eye in the Network tab of the browser developer tools available both on chrome and firefox. It will show you exactly which assets were attempted to be fetched and what went wrong. Anyway that path should be relative to the page. `.` dot means in the same dir, `..` double dots means parent dir. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL

Comment: And as a final note, Bootstrap is an asset with an absolute url and since you say that it doesn't work maybe there's also the chance that you expected it to work out of the internet.. that of course it's impossible since you are not hosting your own bootstrap

Comment: @DiegoD Turns Out I have to add "/Users/MyPC/FixITSite" before "/appdata/ranik.css" for it to pull the css, and also do the same for it to pull Bootstrap, since I have it downloaded because I need to change some values, What makes me confused is how has it worked with only "/appdata/ranik.css" so far, and how it has to be "/Users/MyPC/FixITSite/appdata/ranik.css"

Comment: the bootstrap deal was confusing the question because it was pulled from cdn.jsdelivr.net and didn't match with the relative path affair. Now I get you actually were using your local copy and that's why it was affected. The `/appdata` path worked on LiveServer because there the root was mapped to that relative point in the fs. By root I mean `localhost/`. But when loading the page from the fs, the `/` root would be mapped to C: volume and it can't find the resource `/appdata...`

Comment: I have a Domen Bought, and it doesn't work on there either I always just used /appdata/.. when I want to link to root folder, but It works on half site on half doesn't Hrere is site link: "http://fixit.in.rs/gradjevina/moler/marko-nikolic.html" try going onto "recenzija"

EDIT: Just realized you prob won't be able to open it because it's .rs and not .com

Comment: I could visit that page and I see that the assets not found are FAVICON2.jpg and font-awesome.min.css because they have an incorrect url. Anyway I'm not sure to understand if you are trying to load the page from local fs for some reason. The problem is that those path won't match and you can't edit those html to make it work on both scenarios. Well there's also <base> for basedir but let's ignore it. Or maybe if you put the document root in D:\. Anyway why don't you use LiveServer?

Comment: Let me put it simple. What do I have to write for it to work on my  page, for style to work on "Recenzija"

Comment: The page now returns 404

Comment: I changed the link, here: "http://fixit.in.rs/moler/ime-radnika.html"

Answer (score 0):

remove the first slash "/"

```
    <link href="appdata/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="appdata/radnik.css"  rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: Doesn't work. since the html page isn't in root folder